# PDO login system

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Everything I coded is fine except for the final step which is logging in. I'm asking for it to LOCATION: INDEX.PHP after i submit in the data, it's doing just that, except in index.php it's not giving me the script I asked it to, which is "welcome! you are now logged in".

**index.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        echo 'Welcome! You are now logged in!';
    } else{
        echo '<a href="register.php">Register</a><br /><a href="login.php">Login</a>';
    }
?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="password">
    <input type="submit" value="post">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
        require'core/connect.php';

        $query = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
        $query->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
        $query->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password']);

        if($query->execute() === true){
            header("Location: index.php");
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong!";
        }
    }
?>
```

**register.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
        require'core/connect.php';

        $query = dbConnect()->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)");
        $query->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
        $query->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password']);

        if($query->execute()){
            header("Location: index.php");
        } else{
            echo 'UH OH!';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You need to add `$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];` --- Having `if(isset($_SESSION['username']))` is useless on its own, if you're not assigning it anywhere. This is one way of doing it. `xdazz` seems to have the right idea though.

Comment: Why, why, **why** are you using **plaintext passwords**? This is a terrible idea.

Comment: `echo 'UH OH!';` is right. ---^

Answer (score 0):

`$query->execute()` just check the sql is right, but not check the username and password is right.

So `if($query->execute() === true){` will never check the password is right.

And if the password is right, you have to set the session value before redirect to the index page.

Example:

```
$query = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
$query->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
$query->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password']);
$query->execute()

if($row = $query->fetch()){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    header("Location: index.php");
} else{
    echo "Something went wrong!";
}
```